# Fiware Cosmos Hive Authorization Issue

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, fiware, fiware-cosmos

I'm using a shared instance of [Fiware Cosmos](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/bigdata-analysis-cosmos) (meaning I don't have root privileges). I have until today successfully acessed and managed tables in hive both remotely using jdbc, and Hive CLI.
But now I'm getting this error when starting Hive CLI:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter].
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getEventCounter(ShimLoader.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter.<init>(HiveEventCounter.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:330)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:121)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:664)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jDefault(LogUtils.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:120)
    ... 27 more
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "EventCounter".

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.13.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

I can however perform select and create in the Hive CLI.
If I then try to access Hive remotely, I get this:

```
Connecting to jdbc:hive://x.x.x.x:10000/default?user=user&password=XXXXXXXXXX
Could not establish connection: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I didn't do any changes in code or commands before the errors appeared, and after googling around I haven't found any working solutions.

If anyone can guide me to where the problem is, or how to find it, or even better how to solve it, I'd be grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of these issues were Hive upgrades in Cosmos. A more thorough explanation and solution is found here:

[My Hive client stopped working with Cosmos instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134341/my-hive-client-stopped-working-with-cosmos-instance)

Answer (score 1):

HiveServer2 *(the Hive JDBC service)* is a **very unstable** piece of shoftware. In our Prod cluster we have a CRON job to restart each instance every day, and even then, sometimes it blows OutOfMemory errors then just hangs saying `Connection refused` like you show. Open a ticket to your Hadoop admin so that he/she retarts the damn service.

On the other hand, the `org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter` message smells like someone tried to change a shared config somewhere (or tried to upgrade some JARs) and now Hive believes that it runs on a very, very old version of Hadoop

=> e.g. comments in [Hive-4133](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4133) or that [MapR support post](http://answers.mapr.com/questions/2038/log4j-error-could-not-instantiate-class-org-apache-hadoop-log-metrics-eventcounter.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've asked the admin to look into it.
About the shared config though, is that something I can check, or even fix? Where would i look?

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one to suffer: stackoverflow.com/questions/32134341/my-hive-client-stopped-working-with-cosmos-instance/32134464