# Error accessing Cosmos through Hive

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

Literally from:

https://ask.fiware.org/question/84/cosmos-error-accessing-hive/

---

As the answer in the quoted FIWARE Q&A entry suggest the problem is fixed by now. its here: https://ask.fiware.org/question/79/cosmos-database-privacy/. However, it seems like other issues arisen related to the solution, namely: Through ssh connection, the typing the hive command results in the following error: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13782883/9439517/0d24350a-4a68-11e5-9a46-9d8a24e016d4.png the hiveSQL queries work fine (through ssh) regardless the error message.

When launching exactly the same hiveSQL queries (each one of them worked flawlessly two weeks ago) remotely, the request times out even in absurd time windows (10 minutes). The most basic commands ('use $username;', 'show tables';) also time out.

(The thrift client is: https://github.com/garamon/php-thrift-hive-client)

Since the Cosmos usage is an integral part of our project, it is of utmost importance whether it is a temporal issue caused by the fixes or it is a permanent change in the remote availability (could not identify relevant changes in the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from fixing the issue you mention, we moved to a HiveServer2 deployment instead of the old Hive server (or HiveServer1), which had several performance drawbacks dued to, indeed, the usage of Thrift (particularly, only one connection could be served at the same time). HiveServer2 now allows for parallel queries.

Being said that, most probably the client you are using is not valid anymore since it could be specifically designed for working with a HiveServer1 instance. The good news are it seems there several other client implementations for HS2 using PHP, such as https://github.com/QwertyManiac/hive-hs2-php-thrift (this is the first entry I found when performing a search in Google).

What is true is this is not officialy documented anywhere (it is only mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134341/my-hive-client-stopped-working-with-cosmos-instance) other SOF question). So, nice catch! I'll add it inmediatelly.